# Search for a string in a column and get 14 characters for all occurances in informatica with source oracle

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

My source is Oracle Database. One of my source columns is having data as shown below.
I should search for contact: and get the 14 characters for all occurrences.

Source Column data:

`contact:"abcd"/Location:"India"/contact:"efgh"/Gender:"Male"/contact:"ijkl"/email:"ijkl@gmail.com"`

and so on....

Required output:

```
contact:"abcd",contact:"efgh",contact:"ijkl"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below query for your problem. **I have written this query in Tera data**, if you are using other data base please change the functions accordingly.

I have followed the approach to remove the data which is not related to contact from the data set.

```
with tab as(select 'contact:"abcd"/Location:"India"/contact:"efgh"/Gender:"Male"/contact:"ijkl"/email:"ijkl@gmail.com"' as val)
select oreplace(oreplace(oreplace(val, substr(val,index(val,'/Location:'),index(val,'/Location:')+3),','),(substr(oreplace(val, substr(val,index(val,'/Location:'),index(val,'/Location:')+3) ,','),
index(oreplace(val, substr(val,index(val,'/Location:'),index(val,'/Location:')+3) ,','),'/Gender:'),
index(oreplace(val, substr(val,index(val,'/Location:'),index(val,'/Location:')+3) ,','),'/Gender:')-15)),','),
substr(val,CHARACTER_LENGTH(val)-22),'') as output from tab;
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try in oracle with some changes.